# AutoScroll on Button Click (Outlook Web Add-in 2013 & 2016 & 2019 volume licensed)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, internet-explorer-11

[In our Microsoft certified Outlook Web Add-in](https://appsource.microsoft.com/de-de/product/office/wa200000060?tab=overview&exp=kyyw), when clicking on a button in our react add-in, the add-in "jumps" to the top of the page.  That is pretty much the summary of the issue.  I have several videos / PSRs from various clients wher this behaviour is exhibited.

We have been able to narrow this down to only occurring in Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016 environments.  Thus, it seems that this is related to using IE 11 code to power the Outlook Web Add-in on these environments (depsite IE 11 no longer being supported) as explained in this [Github Post](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/3852).

Our Web App page uses React MUI.

This is pretty annoying behaviour for the user since they need to scroll back down.  However, since IE11 is no longer being used in general, it is very difficult to find information how to resolve this.

Here is an an example URL for a page in our Outlook Web App which works fine in Chrome, Edge, Firefox:  [https://hrb-production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/outlook/dynamic.html?generated_key=72cbd481-0506-4214-8be9-9ffd4dbd0f32&message_id=%3CFR3P281MB1584729A492D137CECEAE03995779%40FR3P281MB1584.DEUP281.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM%3E&sec=18519DEMOS21520](Example page from our App)

We have created a several developer support tickets with Microsoft Developer support, but each time the person responding says they are not responsible.  We have searched extensively for this issue and have not been able to find any information on it.  We have had discussions with the MUI team and we have no idea where to start in terms of how to resolve this situation.

We have not made any code changes.

Anything that points us in the direction of a resolution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue when you run that web app from IE 11, not inside Outlook?

Comment: This was reproducible in Real IE11; it is not happening in the IE11 emulators.

Comment: Well, sounds like the problem is with IE and ReactJS only, not related to the Office JavaScript API (or Outlook) at all.

Comment: Well, given that the only valid use of IE11 code is within outlook, this is definitely an Outlook issue:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/3852#issuecomment-1445470833

Also, to be honest, we are not 100% sure if it is reproducable in IE11 since I have no way of using IE11 anymore since it has been deprecated.

Comment: If any site you visit needs Internet Explorer 11, you can reload it with Internet Explorer mode in Microsoft Edge.  Take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-internet-explorer-in-windows-10-7248a101-d5dd-bded-d843-d9427c42d60f

Comment: @BrendanMay Thank you for bringing up the autoscroll issue in your Outlook Web Add-in on IE11. We understand your concern. Given the complexity of the problem and the limited support for IE11, we are currently evaluating the feasibility of finding a solution. We apologize for any inconvenience caused and will keep you informed of any updates.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - Given that Explorer (ie. Trident +) is here to stay until at least 2029 in the form of Outlook 2019 volume licenced version, (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins#windows), saying that there is limited support for IE11 is a non issue.  

We are asking for support for an environment that has another 6 years of support left.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - Since this issue is actually regarding Trident+ on Outlook 2019, which still has at least 6 years of support left (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins#windows), it really should be supported

Comment: Hi @Brendan May, Outlook 2016 is in extended support (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/outlook-2016), so it is only getting security updates. Additionally, we are not aware of any other instances where this jumping happens. This is likely due to a weird interaction between IE and your code/react mui library. If you can simplify the repro, you may be able to find a workaround for the IE browser that will work in your mainline Add-in.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I do not know why you are commenting on Outlook 2016 being on "Extended Support" since this issue occurs also in Outlook 2019 Volume license which is clearly in mainstream support.

Please advise on how to test with Trident+